# Is it possible to embed an OCI container in a mobile app?

Tags: android, ios, docker

Anyone know of a way (or if it's even possible) to embed an OCI container in an iOS/Android app?

I have a number of use cases, for example, running nginx on mobile.

Thanks in advance for any advice anybody could give!

James